# vuetify's v-autocomplete can't edit text input after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

```
Code is on codepen:
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exYjOZ

If you go to this page and type "joe" into search box, pick one of two Joes that appear, then try to select text in search box, or try using backspace to remove only last character.

You'll see it doesn't allow you to edit text input, it can only remove the whole text in text input after pressing backspace twice.

It should allow me to select/edit text input after selecting an option, just like before selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is using `slot="selection"`

To make it work, you can use `item-text` instead

```
   <v-autocomplete 
      ...
      text="displayText">
   </v-autocomplete>
```

and defined `displayText` method:

```
methods: {
  ...
  displayText (item) {
     return item.firstName + " " + item.lastName
  }
}
```

Please check the [demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/QYwQLQ)

Comment: This approach has one problem - it won't show more than one item in the list if you have two items with same `item-text`.
Check this codepen, I just changed it to have two John Smiths (but note they are different persons, working for different employer etc.) and changed vuetify version to 1.2.9 as that's what I'm using in my project:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaNZNL

Comment: I've created issue on vuetify github too:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6657

Comment: `item-value="id"` needs to be added to fix this behavior. Please update your answer with it and I'll accept it again.